# Is there any way in SQL Server to conditionally return columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure which returns a bunch of numbered columns (I know it's a bad idea but that's what it does) e.g. Question1, Answer1, ... Question125, Answer125.

Now my problem is that if I want to export the results of this procedure to Excel, I get an error when there are more than 256 columns. And there are a handful of unnumbered columns in the query so I have 262 in total - but some of them are blank since the stored procedure doesn't necessarily need to populate all 125 questions and answers.

Is there any way to write a SQL query that will conditionally return a number of columns based on a parameter? I know I can write an if statement on a parameter to return X number of columns or Y depending on whether the parameter is set, but I'd like more fine grained control of it... so if the data I'm dealing with has only 50 questions then it would run up to Question50/Answer50, for instance.

Comment: You have to do this using dynamic SQL.  However, instead of jumping through hoops to make your existing structure work, perhaps you should take this opportunity to rethink your processes.

Comment: The real solution here is to normalise your data. Also, you say *"I get an error when there are more than 256 columns"*. *Why* are you still using `xls` files? They were replaced with `xlsx` back in 2003!

Answer (score 1):

You could use SQL Server's FOR XML to ignore NULL values and build a dynamic list of non-null columns.

You can run this in SSMS:

```
-- Create a mock-up data table.
DECLARE @Data TABLE ( column_1 VARCHAR(10), column_2 VARCHAR(10), column_3 VARCHAR(10), column_4 VARCHAR(10), column_5 VARCHAR(10), pk INT IDENTITY(1,1) );

-- Insert values into every column except for column_4.
INSERT INTO @Data ( column_1, column_2, column_3, column_5 )
    VALUES ( 'Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3', 'Value 5' );

-- View @Data contents.
SELECT * FROM @Data ORDER BY pk;

-- Declare a variable to hold our non-null column list.
DECLARE @columns AS VARCHAR(MAX);

-- SQL/XML Hack: Build the non-null column list with XML's excluding of NULL values.
SELECT
    @columns = STRING_AGG ( cols.column_name, ',' )
FROM (
    SELECT CAST ( ( SELECT * FROM @Data FOR XML PATH ( '' ) ) AS XML ) AS non_null_columns
) AS x
CROSS APPLY (

    SELECT
        x.f.value('fn:local-name(.)','VARCHAR(255)') AS column_name
    FROM non_null_columns.nodes('/*') x(f)

) AS cols;

-- View the column list.
SELECT @columns AS non_null_column_list;

-- Create an executable query with the updated column list.
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = FORMATMESSAGE ( 'SELECT %s FROM %s;', @columns, 'dbo.TableName' );
SELECT @sql AS MyNewSelect;
```

This block:

```
-- View @Data contents.
SELECT * FROM @Data ORDER BY pk;
```

Returns the contents of @Data:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----+
| column_1 | column_2 | column_3 | column_4 | column_5 | pk |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----+
| Value 1  | Value 2  | Value 3  | NULL     | Value 5  |  1 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----+
```

This block:

```
-- View the column list.
SELECT @columns AS non_null_column_list;
```

Shows us what the variable **@columns** holds

```
+----------------------------------------+
|          non_null_column_list          |
+----------------------------------------+
| column_1,column_2,column_3,column_5,pk |
+----------------------------------------+
```

And finally, this block:

```
-- Create an executable query with the updated column list.
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = FORMATMESSAGE ( 'SELECT %s FROM %s;', @columns, 'dbo.TableName' );
SELECT @sql AS MyNewSelect;
```

Shows how we might complete a dynamic sql statement that could then be called with `EXEC`:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                            MyNewSelect                            |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SELECT column_1,column_2,column_3,column_5,pk FROM dbo.TableName; |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This is definitely a **hack**, but it will limit the columns in your dynamic SQL to those that contain values. You really should look to normalize your data for efficiency.

**Note**: You will need a way of restricting the derived table's XML (in my example aliased as "x") to a specific row.